# Japanese animated show in which a Pokemon type monster turned into a stone slab when they died

Tags: story-identification, anime

[image: Similar to this , big creature in size and image made on wall individually]

I still remember a past scene of a series, where a girl/boy with his friends enter a room, like ancient ruins. She/he saw a picture of a monster embedded in a stone slab/wall and mourns at the wall. The unknown creature appeared in the stone wall. There were many of this type present in the room.

Comment: Consider having a look at this checklist about [_"how to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question"_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) to help you remember other important details, and [edit] them in the question.

Comment: Might it be Monster Rancher, about.... Episode 1?!

Comment: Monster Rancher it is, I remember the eye monster and trauma when the monsters died. Somebody please make it an answer.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I did not

Comment: @jo1storm But you're talking about that being the "right" answer, from a different account than the one that asked the question.  That was what caused me to think you'd duplicated.  Sorry, didn't think to check your profile.

Comment: @Trish The only reference Google shows to "Monster Rancher" is a video game series.

Comment: @ZeissIkon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_(TV_series)

Comment: I stand corrected.  @Trish

Comment: @ZeissIkon I agree with the person answering the question (Trish), I am not the person who asked the question. I watched the show in my childhood. Or, to be technical, displaying certainty in the correctness of the answer.

Comment: I think i remember that in the last arc of Yu-Gi-Oh!, we learn that the card where original monsters that get stored in stone slabs..

Answer (score 3):

## [Monster Rancher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_(TV_series))

### aka モンスターファーム (Monsutā Fāmu)

### aka [Monster Farm: Enbanseki no Himitsu](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1469/Monster_Farm__Enbanseki_no_Himitsu)

[image]

#### Episode 1

The main character of the Isekai is displaced into the world of his favorite video game and ends up in some kind of ruinied temple. The female counterpart with her eye-monster flees into said temple, it comes to a comedic clash with pursuing monsters. There are frescos of monsters on the temple, and they try to resurrect a monster from the Monster-Farmer CD

Monsters can be *created* from slabs with such a temple, and after death turn into rocky remains.

Answer (score 1):

**Monster Farm: Enbanseki no Himitsu (1999)**

This is how death for monsters works:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A tree isn't a stone or ceramic plaque on a wall...

Comment: I know. It's only a stone slab. Comments suggested this title as an answer, so I provided pictures of how death works in Monster Farm.

Comment: Monster Farm and Monster Rancher aren't quite the same, at least in English.  I have no Japanese, so can't comment on the translation of the original title.

Comment: @ZeissIkon they actually are... https://myanimelist.net/anime/1469/Monster_Farm__Enbanseki_no_Himitsu

Comment: The *words* aren't quite the same -- a farm is different from a ranch (subtly).  The two names for the game and TV series might well be alternate translations from the same Japanese.

Comment: @ZeissIkon indeed, in JApan it is called Monster Farm